What is this type of slotted wall-mounting arrangement called?
I can't find a real-life example, but I know I've seen hooks like this before. It's not a J-hook, or S-hook, or French cleat. It consists of one piece that has mounting slot that curves upward, and another piece with a long flat slot hole that slides onto the curved piece.


Not what you’ve drawn, but image search ‘flush mount hangers’ and you’ll see similar function.

"Flat hook" comes to mind.

See https://www.google.com/search?q=lashing+flat+j-hook

Size? Weight capacity needed?

It's really just a variation of a French cleat. What problem are you trying to solve?

Weight--maybe 45 pounds. More info: I built an outdoor shed for a water heater. The water heater is an electric heat pump and has needed a couple of service calls already, and the tech needed to get into the top, so I built the shed with all sides and roof easy to remove, in case he needs to service it again. For the front cover, instead of putting it on hinges, I wanted a way to hang it, but didn't want to use standard hooks because it would dangle too low. French cleat would probably do the trick. Thanks everybody!
